# Gallery Images could not be shown

Tags: images, pages, gallery

I have more than 50 pages on my WordPress site and there is a image gallery (WordPress Gallery, not an extension) in each of them.

But now, all of them don't show their images, and in edit mode say's that could not find any image.

I should notice that i already changed link of the those pages parent, but change it to previous. but images not shown too.

Notice: when the images were well, Wordpress version was 3.4 and i updated it to 4.3. may the update process makes problem?

Comment: Are those images available in media library?

Comment: Yes, there are.

Comment: but all of may galleries gone.

Comment: When you see the images in pages on live site do you see full image url? are they broken? Sorry, too less information here to go on..

Comment: I have made a gallery on put it on page and now, my pages are white, like a empty page.